# How can I calculate the change percentage between the current and the previous row in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a table called **bookings** with the following columns:

**starttime (timestamp)**

**slots (int)**

I would like to sum up the booked slots grouped by day, then calculate the change % compared to the previous day.

This query almost does that, but for some reason the percentages are not correct:

```
SELECT starttime::date AS "Dates", SUM(slots) AS "Slots", 
(SUM(Slots)/LAG(SUM(Slots)) OVER (ORDER BY starttime::date))::NUMERIC(3,2) AS "Change (%)"
FROM cd.bookings
GROUP BY 1;
```

And this is the output:

```
DATES        Slots  Change(%)
"2012-07-03"    10  NULL
"2012-07-04"    22  2.00
"2012-07-05"    19  0.00
"2012-07-06"    23  1.00
"2012-07-07"    42  1.00
"2012-07-08"    36  0.00
"2012-07-09"    43  1.00
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Integer division. Cast the sums to a data type like `double precision`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to a non-integer *before* division:

```
SELECT starttime::date AS "Dates", SUM(slots) AS "Slots", 
       (SUM(Slots) * 1.0 /
        LAG(SUM(Slots)) OVER (ORDER BY starttime::date)
        )::NUMERIC(3,2) AS "Change (%)"
FROM cd.bookings
GROUP BY 1;
```

Postgres does integer division when both operands are an integer, so 0/1 is 0 rather than 0.5.